# Undefined reference to function of another lib

Tags: c, gcc, linker

Yeah, I know many people asked that question before, but I still can't understand the problem in my case

I have 2 libs, let's say liba & libb. libb uses liba but is compiled in .a so it should link at compile time.
I have the following GCC command:

```
gcc -o my_program  obj/mymain.o obj/myutils.o liba/liba.a libb/libb.a -Iinclude -Iliba -Ilibb
```

But GCC is returning me a lot of "Undefined reference to ..." from libb functions to liba functions.

What is happening? What should I do?

Thank you

Comment: Could you show the code where you include the one library to the other? And the whole error message?

Comment: Order matters. If library B depends on library A, then B needs to come *before* A on the command line.

Comment: About `-I`, the use is intended as I have headers in those dirs, so I guess this is OK.
In fact, this was an ordre problem as @Someprogrammerdude pointed out.... Thanks for help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The evaluation of commands on a `link` compile command is very important.

When the compiler sees .o files, they get added to the target binary automatically, so all .o files are present.  That leaves a list of undefined entities which need to be found.

The next stage is to look through the libraries.  Each library is searched, and the .o elements of each library which fulfills an undefined reference is added to the target binary.  That always resolves some issues.  However, it may also have further requirements.  So adding part of a library may add to the required elements to be satisfied.

When a library requires another library, it needs to be specified after something which required it, and before the libraries which satisfy its requirements.

There is a chance if the .o files also require the same parts of a library, this issue can crop up when code is deleted from a .o (removing the mechanism which pulls in the library part).